# Can grep show output only if the line contain another search string?

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to get an output based on second match on the same line. For example I am having a .log file of program. When some process of the program stop working properly, the .log file start having lines which contains "ERROR" .......... ..... ......... ... EG_10. So I am trying to output just the number 10, ONLY if the line contains the word "ERROR" in it, and if there is no "ERROR" in the line not to print anything. The problem is that this processes log files are located in different directories. The structure is:

```
root@vm1:~#/something/differentproceses_10/logs/logfile.log
root@vm1:~#/something/differentproceses_11/logs/logfile.log
root@vm1:~#/something/differentproceses_12/logs/logfile.log
```

I managed to get only the numbers, but the problem is that it get the numbers from all the .log files not just the number from a file which contain "ERROR" in it.

```
root@vm1:~# tail -n 10 something/*/*/logfile.log | grep -o 'ERROR\|EG_.[0-9]' | sed  's/[^0-9. ]\+\|^[^0-9]\+//g' | awk '{print $1}' 
10
11
12
```

Comment: You are looking for `ERROR` _or_ `EG_.[0-9]`; you clearly want _and_ though it's not clear whether the order is significant.

Comment: I am looking for the number from ```EG_.[0-9]``` This is how the line in .log file looks like 
```
(ERROR) [pool-1-thread-2] [something.comsomething.db]: [CHC] existence query => SELECT * FROM EG_10 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

And I am trying to get just the number from the table query in the log. I need the number printed only if there is ```ERROR``` contained in the line

Comment: You are repeating information from the question, rather than clarifying anything. The duplicate has a number of solutions to this problem. Briefly, `sed -n '/ERROR/s/.*EG_\([1-9][0-9]\)\b.*/\1/p' /something/*/logs/logfile.log`

Comment: And if you do want to clarify the question, please [edit] it rather than divide the information between the actual question and the comments.

Comment: I am sorry this was my first question and I am no quite familiar with the rules and the forms of structure here. Thank you for your replay. And yes your answer was exactly what i was trying to do. Thank you again.